# Open Whatsapp Desktop instead of Web version when using Chrome link

Tags: windows, google-chrome, whatsapp

When I run this ("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=number") in Chrome it asks to open whatsapp web edition, but I want to use my desktop edition for these kind of links.

How can I set the default in Chrome for these kind of links?

Comment: I don't think there is any correct way to make google chrome open an app unless the website suggests that it should be opened using a desktop app. For example, Github desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If the `whatsapp://` protocol is set on your computer, you can use:

- `whatsapp://send?phone={number}`

Another thing, there's also the `api.whatsapp.com` URL, that can be used in the same way and it's the one shown in [WhatsApp's FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/). I guess that if someday they'll add an option that will ask you in which one to open - it will be with the `api` URL, which makes more sense for that purpose. So anyway maybe it's better using this one, instead of the `web` one.

Comment: Work perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also write
[https://wa.me/{phonenumber}](https://wa.me/%7Bphonenumber%7D)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).